# How to update a record with multiple keys

Tags: sql, android

I am trying a database app on Android.
I want to use the SQLiteDatabase ***update(...)*** convenience method to update a record.
Normally, for a WHERE clause of a single key this is working. Following code is working fine:-

```
values.put("testname", "Quiz1");  
mDB.update("Tests", values, "id=?", new String[]{"2"}); //this statement works
```

However, I want to update a column in a table which has a combination of two keys as the unique identifier. I tried the following. This executes without exception, but nothing is updated.

```
values.put("score", 60);  
mDB.update("Results", values, "studentid=? AND testid=?", 
    new String[] { "2,1" }); // this statement does not work`
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert on Android or SQLite, but I think your statement should be:

```
mDB.update("Results", values, "studentid=? AND testid=?", new String[] { "2","1" });
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

> values.put("score", 60);
>   mDB.update("Results", values, "studentid=? AND testid=?", 
>       new String[] { "2,1" }); // this statement does not work`

The value `"2,1"` is just one String object so before update, the Database Management System will check if there is a record where `studentid="2,1"` and if no record no row will be affected.

If we want to test for both `studentid` and `testid` there must be two values inside the String[] array, by instance:

```java
values.put("score", 60);  
mDB.update("Results", values, "studentid=? AND testid=?", 
    new String[] { "2","1" });
```

Where `studentid` will be tested with value `2` and `testid` with value `1`. This is just to help new readers to understand the difference, why your snippet did not work and why @jvenema one's worked.